# Javascript - throwing, instantiating new Error() and populating its custom properties in a single line

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to do all of this one line?

```js
if (!user) {
    const error = new Error('Invalid user.')
    error.data = someObject
    error.code = 401
    throw error
}
```

For example (but with populated data and code properties)

```js
if (!user) throw new Error('Invalid user.')
```

Comment: You can create your class extending Error and call like `if (!user) throw new MyError(message, data, code)`

Comment: For clarification and future reader: `class MyError extends Error{constructor(message,data,code){super(message)this.data=data this.code=code}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to add custom properties to the error object, you could do something like:

```js
if (!user) {
  throw Object.assign(new Error('Invalid user.'), {
    data: someObject,
    code: 401
  });
}
```

Not exactly a one-liner, but you get the idea.

It would be better if you construct your own class extending `Error` to handle additional properties like `data` and `code`. (See @Rajesh's comment)

Comment: It is a one-liner! `if (!user) throw Object.assign(new Error('Invalid user.'), {code: 401, data: errors})`. Thank you!